# Fail running glassfish server in Netbeans because it is not contained

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I try to run glassfish server in Netbeans using this

To Start the GlassFish Server Using NetBeans IDE
Click the Services tab.
Expand the Servers node.
Right-click the GlassFish Server instance and select Start.

However the tab in output for Glassfish Server 4.1.1 gives me this and always ask for credentials:

```
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
May 29, 2016 5:22:43 ΜΜ com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
May 29, 2016 5:22:43 ΜΜ com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
May 29, 2016 5:22:43 ΜΜ com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
May 29, 2016 5:22:43 ΜΜ com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner startBundles
WARNING: Can not start bundle file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/modules/core.jar because it is not contained in the list of installed bundles.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@21e6029c in service registry.
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\lib\templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\lib\templates\logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=C:\Users\Alia-PC\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\config\GF_4.1.1\domain1\config\logging.properties
Info:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (build 1)
Info:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Info:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Info:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 5.361ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 5ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 5ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 4ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
Info:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (1) startup time : Felix (41.577ms), startup services(16.234ms), total(57.811ms)
Info:   JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [100]
Info:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://alia:8686/jndi/rmi://alia:8686/jmxrmi
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
Info:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@4074023c as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@38eb2fb0.
```